# Could not resolve argument $token on override FOS Controller in symfony 4.3

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle

Firstly, I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

I want to override a FOS Controller. I successfully redirect but not getting perfect  **`/register/confirm/{token}`**  work . 
I am getting a token error.

***Getting Error:***
Could not resolve argument $token of "App\Controller\RegistrationController::confirmaction()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?

[image]

My Code

**RegistrationController.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class RegistrationController extends \FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController
{
    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $formFactory;
    private $userManager;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory     = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager     = $userManager;
        $this->tokenStorage    = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump('d1');
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }


    public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
    {
        dump('d');
        $userManager = $this->userManager;

        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    public function confirmedAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/confirmed.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession($request->getSession()),
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getTargetUrlFromSession(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $key = sprintf('_security.%s.target_path', $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getProviderKey());

        if ($session->has($key)) {
            return $session->get($key);
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

**Service.yml**

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'


services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    app.fos_overriding_routes:
        class: App\EventListener\FosOverridingRoutes
        arguments: ['@router']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    App\Controller\RegistrationController:
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
        autowire: true
        arguments:
            $eventDispatcher: '@event_dispatcher'
            $formFactory: '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
            $userManager: '@fos_user.user_manager'
            $tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
```

**routes.yaml**

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
#    prefix: setting

fos_user_registration_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction}
    #prefix: /register/

#
fos_user_registration_confirm:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::confirmAction }
    #path: /register/
    #prefix: /confirm/{token}
    prefix: /register/
```

Comment: Have you already try with $request->get('token') instead of passing directly $token as action parameters?

Comment: i try to that. but not working main register link. *http://localhost:8000/register/* same error are getting the main register

Comment: What is the full URL where you get this error? Also did you try to leave out the "defaults" entry in your routes.yaml and put in "path:/confirm/{token}" instead?

Comment: *http://localhost:8000/register/confirm/mQPeUOFDBso-RgA31I2KQmI5mkrMmRZ0MXk8-ozyxEE* as per your answer i am getting a dump . but error getting this URL *http://localhost:8000/register/* i think router problem?

Comment: So your confirm URL works with the adjustment?

Comment: yup. but see my router.yaml  if any mistake are there? because i confuse prefix

Comment: Check out my answer, let me know if it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't combine the resource entry with your own controller entry when trying to overwrite the controller action

Change the routing to:

```
fos_user_registration_register:  
    controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction
    path: /register


fos_user_registration_confirm:
    controller:App\Controller\RegistrationController::confirmAction
    path: /register/confirm/{token}
```

You can also put the routing in your controller with annotations:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing.html